# Optmization of non-convex and non-concave function

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, non-convex

I am trying to implement a profit optimization function in a cloud computing environment. Objective function is claimed to neither convex and nor concave. The function along with constraints is given as under

[image]

The authors say that objective function becomes convex if we solve it iteratively that is first fixing P_jk and optimize φ_jk and vice versa till solution converge. I am not sure whether this is a right argument. 
Secondly, I have implemented the problem using Matlab fmincon, after running optimization, the value of phi (optimized) is set to all 1s, meaning 100% resource utilization which is not practically true. For example, if we have a cloud with 48 servers and 30 processing tasks to be executed, they would be assigned to any of the 30 servers whose phi may be between 0 to 1 but for rest of the servers, phi should not be 1. If you can kindly comments on this issue also? Is my understanding correct?
Thirdly, if fmincon is a right tool to use in this case?
I shall appreciate any help.

Comment: There seem to be two different `f1`'s in the objective.

Comment: I am sorry there were two typos, now I have corrected them.

Comment: Not sure if this iterative scheme is guaranteed to converge to the optimal solution. For non-convex problems always try different starting points to see if there are multiple local optima. Otherwise use a global solver such as Baron, Couenne or Antigone.